# How to simulate args inside a php file?

Tags: php, args

```
PHP file.php arg1 arg2
```

Now I want to hardcode `arg1` and `arg2` into `file.php`,how to do it?

Comment: please give an example of what you mean by hardcode into file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried it, but the arguments are contained in a certain array `$argv`. So you have to set those entries if you want to hardcode them:

```
$argc = 3; // number of arguments + 1
$argv[0] = 'file.php'; // contains script name
$argv[1] = 'arg1';
$argv[2] = 'arg2';
```

`$argv` is a [reserved variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).

But note that the first two parameter that you specify via command line will always be overwritten by `arg1` and `arg2`.

Instead, if you need these values always in your script you should define them as normal variables at the top of your script:

```
$var1 = 'arg1';
$var2 = 'arg2';
```

or even as constants:

```
define('CONST1', 'arg1');
define('CONST2', 'arg2');
```

---

If you only want to provide `arg1`, `arg2` as parameter via the command line, then you can just access them via `$argv[1]` and `$argv[2]`, no need to mess with `$argv`;

Answer (score 0):

you would use [argv()](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) inside your php script to get the arguments

```
foreach ($argv as $args){
  print $args."\n";
}
```

element 0 contains the script name. the rest are the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test how many arguments to the function, then do something accordingly.

```
 function foo()
    {
       $numargs = func_num_args();
       echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
       if ($numargs >= 2) {
           echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
       }
       $arg_list = func_get_args();
       for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
           echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
       }
    }

    foo(1, 2, 3);
```